# Value of Array not being incremented

Tags: arrays, bash

I am attempting to increment the index of my array using the following way
however it seems to overwrite the previous index which is wrong. Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong.

```
CURRENT_INDEX=${#ARRAY_EXIST_ONLY_IN_STEPPER[@]} 
((CURRENT_INDEX++))
ARRAY_SAMENAME_SAME_SIZE[${CURRENT_INDEX}]=${FILENAMEONLY}
echo "File is present in both and both file sizes are the same : "${FILENAMEONLY} " Placed in  ${CURRENT_INDEX}"
```

The above code is actually being used here and I could tell the array index is being overwritten. Every-time a new entry is made in an array it is suppose to extract the current index then increment it by one and then use that index.However it looks like it is not doing that. Any suggestions on why the arrays are overwriting their previous index ?

```
declare -a ARRAY_SAMENAME_DIFFERENT_SIZE;
declare -a ARRAY_SAMENAME_SAME_SIZE;
declare -a ARRAY_EXIST_ONLY_IN_STEPPER

for var in ${ARRAY_WAV_FILES_IN_STEPPER[@]}
do
  FILENAMEEXTENSION=${var##*/}              
  FILENAMEONLY=${FILENAMEEXTENSION%.*}
  ################################################################################
  FIND_COMMAND_RESULT=""
  FindCommand="find ${ARRAY[1]} -iname ${FILENAMEEXTENSION}"
  FIND_COMMAND_RESULT=$(${FindCommand}) 
  echo "Working with : "${var}
  if [[ !  -z  ${FIND_COMMAND_RESULT}  ]]
  then
     #The file is present in the 0th Array index directory 
     #check if they are the same size
     CURRENT_FILESIZE=$(stat -c%s ${var})
     REMOTE_FILESIZE=$(stat -c%s ${FIND_COMMAND_RESULT})
     if [ ${CURRENT_FILESIZE} -eq ${REMOTE_FILESIZE} ] 
     then
             #The file is present in both and both file sizes are the same - Record it
             CURRENT_INDEX=${#ARRAY_EXIST_ONLY_IN_STEPPER[@]} 
             ((CURRENT_INDEX++))
             ARRAY_SAMENAME_SAME_SIZE[${CURRENT_INDEX}]=${FILENAMEONLY}
             echo "File is present in both and both file sizes are the same : "${FILENAMEONLY} " Placed in  ${CURRENT_INDEX}"
     else
             #The file is present in both but they have different sizes
             echo "The file is present in both but they have different sizes : " ${var}
             CURRENT_INDEX=${#ARRAY_SAMENAME_DIFFERENT_SIZE[@]} 
             ((CURRENT_INDEX++))
             ARRAY_SAMENAME_DIFFERENT_SIZE[${CURRENT_INDEX}]=${FILENAMEONLY}
     fi
  else
      #The file exists only in stepper
      echo "The file is only in stepper : " ${var}
      CURRENT_INDEX=${#ARRAY_EXIST_ONLY_IN_STEPPER[@]} ; ((CURRENT_INDEX++))
      ARRAY_EXIST_ONLY_IN_STEPPER[${CURRENT_INDEX}]=${FILENAMEONLY}
  fi
done
```

Comment: @Gene, one reason is that the shell is available on every system, but the same is not true of Perl.

Comment: Another is that people try to write shell scripts as if they were writing C.

Answer (score 2):

There's a simpler way to add an item to an array:

```
ARRAY_SAMENAME_SAME_SIZE+=("${FILENAMEONLY}")
```